# Como redirigir a un perfil de usuario mediante la URL de esta forma www.midominio.com/NombreDelUsuario con htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> No es muy común que este haciendo preguntas en estos sitios ya que
> normalmente busco primero mi problema en Google y "casi siempre" consigo las
> respuestas antes de preguntarlas.
>
> Pero en este caso no e conseguido una respuesta o al menos no he
> logrado encontrar una manera correcta de buscarla.

Intento redirigir a perfiles de una forma parecida a como lo hace Facebook, utilizando httaccess. Un ejemplo seria así [www.midominio.com](http://www.midominio.com) **/Juan** y que esta te lleve directo al perfil del usuario.
Logre hacer algo parecido con este bloque de codigo:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteEngine On

# Redirigir a perfil de usuario
RewriteRule ^([.-A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?profile_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Pero algo me dice que haciéndolo de esta forma tendré problemas graves a futuro, sabrá alguien si esta forma es la correcta, o si habrá una mejor forma de hacerlo?

Hay quienes solucionan este problema de esta forma.
[www.midominio.com](http://www.midominio.com) **/users/** Juan .

Pero esa forma no es la deseada, la idea es que el nombre del usuario sea ingresado en la url de manera directa, como explique arriba.

Answer (score 0):

En principio, se puede hacer con el concepto requerido, pero deberás tener en cuenta varias cosas, por ejemplo:

- A la hora de generar usuarios, validar el nombre para que no tomen valores reservados que puedan generar un conflicto (por ejemplo, que ninguno se llame index.php o contacto.html), evitar caracteres especiales, otros símbolos (?, #, /, ", ', etc), espacios, etc.
- ¿Los nombres de usuario son case sensitive? Quizás convenga considerar todo en minúsculas a la hora de validarlo (tanto el valor de la variable como el valor buscado, por ejemplo, en una base de datos), y que funcione de cualquier manera.
- Sanitizar profile_id antes de procesar el valor de la variable. Importante, por seguridad.
- Contemplar también la URL con / final.

Adicionalmente, si no enviarás parámetros en la URL, no es necesario usar `QSA`.